# The element of the two statements are mutually referenced with peg.js

Tags: peg, pegjs

define the block like this

```
compound_stat
= '{' decl exp_stat '}'

exp_stat
= exp ';'

decl
= decl_specs id ';'

decl_specs
= 'int'/'float'

id
=name:[a-z]+ {return name.join("");}

exp_stat
  = left:multiplicative "+" right:exp_stat { right=right+1;return left + right; }
  / multiplicative

multiplicative
  = left:primary "*" right:multiplicative { return left * right; }
  / primary

primary
  = integer
  /id
  / "(" exp_stat:exp_stat ")" { return exp_stat; }


integer "integer"
  = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```

want to achieve that {float a =3;a*3+1;}
return 10
i don't know how to reference the  id in two statements which are "decl" and "exp_stat". who can share an example?

Comment: Are you aware that you have two different rules named `exp_stat`?

Comment: i made a mistake .it should be exp

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need to define, intern and ultimately reference your declared variables.

So when you say: 'int a=1;', you want to save (intern) that value somewhere so you can retrieve it when you need it elsewhere.

Lucky for us, `pegjs` supports "global" code sections in which you can do exactly that, as in:

```
{
  /**
   * Storage of Declared Variables
   * @type {Object}
   */
  const vars = {}
}
```

Then, when your parser recognizes a valid declaration, you:

```
vars[id] = { name: id, type: spec, value: val }

/* where id is the name (symbol) of your declared variable: 'a'
   spec is the value of your decl_spec: 'float'
   and val is the value you want to intern
 */
```

Finally, when you need the value, you recognize the symbol in an expression and do your substitution as you evaluate the expression.

For the full working example, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/raisch/440c65d0c6c5d84bf794f831b6ebed60) which provides a fully working parser for your language specification.